# PHP get weekday of setDate()

Tags: php, date, weekday

I'm trying to create a calendar in php. I need to get the weekday (sunday, monday, etc) of the first day of the month. My code so far is:

```
<?php
$current_month = date("n");
$current_year = date("Y");
$first_day_of_month = new DateTime();
$first_day_of_month -> setDate($current_year,$current_month,1);
?>
```

I'm stuck on how to get the weekday of the set date (the first of the month). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `format` function of this class and give the format you desire.

Here is the list of date format that should work:

[date format](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php)

example:

```
$first_day_of_month->format('D');
```

Note: Take a look at the class definition for more question:

[DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/class.datetime.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
 echo date("l", mktime(0,0,0,date("n"),1,date("Y")));
```

In your case,

```
echo date("l", mktime(0,0,0,$current_month,1,$current_year));
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a extended code for you

```
<?php
$current_month = date("n");
$current_year = date("Y");
$first_day_of_month = new DateTime();
$first_day_of_month -> setDate($current_year,$current_month,1);

$timestamp = strtotime($first_day_of_month);

$day = date('D', $timestamp);
var_dump($day);

?>
```

this will give you that day .

Answer (score 0):

$timestamp = strtotime($current_year-$current_month-1);
$day = date('D', $timestamp);

echo $day;

I hope above mentioned code will work for you.

Pawan